# display only a certain word in a string

Tags: python, django

I'm making an API call that fetches me something like

```
Session #1 - ABC
Session #2 - DEF
Session #3 - PQR
```

I want to render only the values after the hyphen (ABC, DEF, PQR) on a page.

Logically, remove all the characters upto the nth character(hyphen, in this case). How do I do that, though?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` and take the second argument:

```
split('-')[1].strip()
```

Example:

```
f = "Session #1 - ABC"
s = f.split('-')[1].strip()
```

Output:

```
ABC
```

Comment: If the string's format is always the same ie, "ABC", "DEF", etc is at the end, you could use `str.rsplit(" ", 1)[-1]` instead

Comment: She says explicitly after the hyphen.. another solution is take the last 3 characters `f[-3:]`

Comment: @Joe the OP didn't explicitely specify that the value of interest would always be of length 3 either.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes, i know, but it was referred to Jebby's comment "if the format is always the same". In fact i havent written that as answer :)

Comment: Potential problem: a string like `Foo - bar - qux`.